# Remove 'b' character do in front of a string literal in Python 3

Tags: python, string, encryption, binary

I am new in python programming and i am a bit confused. I try to get the bytes from a string to hash and encrypt but i got

```
b'...'
```

b character in front of string just like the below example. Is any way avoid this?.Can anyone give a solution? Sorry for this silly question

```
import hashlib

text = "my secret data"
pw_bytes = text.encode('utf-8')
print('print',pw_bytes)
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(pw_bytes)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 print b'my secret data'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680634/1236128

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Decoding is redundant**

You only had this "error" in the first place, because of a misunderstanding of what's happening.

**You get the `b` because you encoded to `utf-8` and now it's a bytes object.**

```
 >> type("text".encode("utf-8"))
 >> <class 'bytes'>
```

**Fixes:**

1. You can just print the string first
2. Redundantly decode it after encoding

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? It's the one below that is. This one is too much talk...The answer below by krock is the answer. And by the way,  str(x) does not remove the b

Comment: First answers with no explanation or as you put it "talk" are useless. Code only answers are frowned upon here. Second, I didn't say str(x) removed the b.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: *this not an answer !*

Comment: @dsgdfg Just because you didnt understand it doesnt mean its not an answer. It just means you come to stackoverflow looking for copy paste code without acually knowing what youre doing or attempting to understand even a modicum of the code you write. How much simpler are you looking for than a 50 character 2 bullet point itemization of how you screwed up?

Answer (score 275):

This should do the trick:

```
pw_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: It's not working in my case. I'm using python3.

Comment: Thanks, It worked with python 3.7.
@BiratBose: I think it should work, can you provide the code and result ?

Comment: @BiratBose, I am using python 3.7 and decoding worked for me.

Comment: Works with python 3.7.3. Thanks

Comment: `pw_bytes = pw_bytes.decode("utf-8")` should work

Comment: Excellent idea. it really works. Thank you very much

Comment: works in 2022 python3.9

Answer (score 36):

Here u Go

```
f = open('test.txt','rb+')
ch=f.read(1)
ch=str(ch,'utf-8')
print(ch)
```

Comment: You introduced a filesystem object into the mix?  Why?

Comment: Didn't get it, please can you elaborate more?

Comment: I've used this in Python 3.7.3 to remove the `b' '` enclosing the value returned by `subprocess.check_output()` and it works.