# Why does the byte literal symbol keep appearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I print out the value, it is fine. But finally it gives an error as the b' messes up the name. I am reading files f0.txt, f1.txt; plan to modify them and save them with their same names.

Tried the utf-8 decoding solution offered at [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016946/remove-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal-in-python-3/42303447) here, not working.

```
path ='/kaggle/input/'
print (path)
i = 1
part = 'f' + str(i)
print (part) #the byte literal symbol b' doesn't appear here
for i in range(0,3):
    part = 'f' + str(i)
    file_path = path + part + '.csv'
    print (file_path) # the byte literal symbol b' doesn't appear here too
    pd = pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace = True) # error in this line
    np.savetxt(part.txt, pd,fmt='%.18e', delimiter=',', newline='n', header='Time,ID,lat,long,speed',)

b'/kaggle/input/f0.csv' does not exist
```

The command

```
pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/f2.txt', delim_whitespace = True)
```

is working.

The error in the first case is:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-37d9e9ecc542> in <module>
      8     file_path = path + part + '.csv'
      9     print (file_path)
---> 10     pd = pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace = True)
     11     np.savetxt(part.txt, pd,fmt='%.18e', delimiter=',', newline='n', header='Time,ID,lat,long,speed',)
     12 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    438 
    439     # Create the parser.
--> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    786 
--> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    788 
    789     def close(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1013         if engine == 'c':
-> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1707 
-> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1709 
   1710         passed_names = self.names is None

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'/kaggle/input/f0.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: Are you aware that the filesystem has its own encoding?

Comment: @wjandrea nope, I just started working on python. By file system, you mean the OS or the compiler?

Comment: A [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) is basically a data structure that holds files. But anyway, looking at Grismar's answer, it's not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Even this reproduces the behaviour you're seeing:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Assuming you don't have a file called test.csv in the working folder, it results in:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'test.csv' does not exist: b'test.csv'
```

So, it appears the `.read_csv()` method accepts a string as a filename, but turns it into a byte sequence before using it to open the file and when that fails, that is the value that is reported.

It is important to note that the value printed (i.e. `b'test.csv'`) does not mean that the `b` is now part of the filename. It simply means "a byte sequence containing `test.csv`", to set it apart from `'test.csv'`, without a `b`, which means "a string containing `test.csv`".

Comment: Parts of pandas are written in cython. Cython can get better performance by using c types instead of regular python types. I believe that's the reason the file path is encoded to bytes here.

Comment: @Grismar if I directly refer to the file from the containing directory, I get a similar error as you. If I reference from another directory, the ` b' ` gets added as the first letter as mentioned in the post.

Comment: @user3656142 as far as I can tell, the `b` is always displayed when referring to non-existent files, as the error message is generated as a result of calling `.read_csv()`. It doesn't matter whether you reference a file inside or outside the working directory of your script. If you see different behaviour (for non-existent files) in different cases, please provide examples for both in your question and I will try to update my answer accordingly. Note that the `b` is not actually part of the value - it's merely printed by Python to indicate that it is a byte sequence and not a character string.

Comment: @Grismar The file exists in the directory. The ls command shows the files to be there. And in situations where the file I referenced to was not there, the `b never appeared.

Comment: @user3656142 In your code, double-check that you're in the right place and the file exists with `print(repr(os.getcwd()))` and `print(os.listdir())`

Comment: I'd recommend checking that from your code, also do you have a directory called `kaggle` at the root of your file system? It seems likely that you meant to write `kaggle/input` instead of `/kaggle/input`.