# Extra character in base64 encoding

Tags: python, python-requests

```
username = 'root'
password = '1234'
auth_str = '%s:%s' % (username, password)
b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode())

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % b64_auth_str}
```

Above is my code for base encoding. My header become `{'Authorization': "Basic b'cm9vdDoxMjM0'"}`.
But, what I need is `{'Authorization': 'Basic cm9vdDoxMjM0'}`

Why extra char and how to remove those?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016946/remove-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as decoding the result of `base64.b64encode`

```
import base64

creds = b'root:1234'
b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(creds).decode('ascii')
headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {b64_auth_str}'}

print(headers)  # {'Authorization': 'Basic cm9vdDoxMjM0'}
```