# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, atom-editor, tweepy

I'm playing around with tweepy but I'm not sure that's the issue, maybe with my editor (Atom)?

I've successfully pulled data from the api using:

```
users = client.get_users_followers(id=id)
```

I then wish to print the data.

```
for user in users.data:
    print(user.username)
```

I get the error AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'

If I do

```
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

It prints all the data so I know the api is working, but doesn't allow me to isolate it to just the usernames.

The data output looks like this (small snippet) and I just want to print the username

b'{"data":[{"id":"737596418123124736","name":"Gary Surridge","username":"LordSurridge"}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Remove 'b' character do in front of a string literal in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016946/remove-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal-in-python-3)

```
utf = user.encode('utf-8')
print(utf[0].username)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this but it hasn't solved the issue. I'm also not sure why this isn't an issue for other people from when I've googled twitter api