# How to convert binary data from mongodb to string in Python properly

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I have an image that is saved in mongodb as a series of bytes (see screenshot 1).
[image]
As you can this string contains an apostrophe as the first symbol and the same apostrophe at the end of the string.

Then I retrieve this field in Python and encode it via base64:

```
@app.route("/personal_account", methods=['GET'])
def personal_account():
    # get avatar field from database
    user = list(db.users.find({"user_id": session.get("user_id")}))[0]
    return render_template("personal_account.html",
                           username = user.get("user_name"),
                           email = user.get("email"),
                           avatar = base64.b64encode(user.get("avatar")))
```

Then for some reason after encoding I see that first and last apostrophes have been encoded too (see screenshot 2, b&#39;):
[image]

So I cannot parse the image into my html form because of this couple of apostrophes.

The question is: how can I get rid of this apostrophes in order to parse the image in binary format properly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also note the `b` preceding that. That looks like a bytestring prefix (`b'This is a bytestring'`). You'll likely need to encode that first. And how are you plugging that string into the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the decision.
I needed to encode bytes from mongodb to base64 first and then decode the bytestring to string.

Thanks @Carcigenicate and @0x00 for help!

Also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016946/remove-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal-in-python-3) was very helpful in my case.

```
@app.route("/personal_account", methods=['GET'])
def personal_account():
    # get avatar field from database
    user = list(db.users.find({"user_id": session.get("user_id")}))[0]
    img_from_mongo = user.get("avatar") # <class 'bytes'>, bytestring from mongodb
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(img_from_mongo) # bytestring encoded in base64
    base64_str = base64_bytes.decode("utf-8") # string that is decoded from bytes object
    return render_template("personal_account.html",
                           username = user.get("user_name"),
                           email = user.get("email"),
                           bytes_line = user.get("avatar"),
                           avatar = base64_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flask with Jinja2 templating, then by default its configured to escapes special characters to [prevent XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding).

If you need to disable autoescaping for just one variable you can use the filter [`safe`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#html-escaping)

```html
<img src="{{ avatar | safe }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps! Unfortunately, in my case the problem was a little deeper and I was forced to get rid of apostrophes before passing the string to html.